# What are "greens" in relation to clothing?

Tags: meaning

What are "greens?" Work clothes? Here is the context:

> ...and gave me a leather jacket to cover my **greens** and loaned me...

The quote is from *One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest*, a novel about a mental patient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Scrubs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrubs_%28clothing%29), green or  blue clothing worn by hospital staff.

Edit: Or mental patients (just realized where the quote was from)

Comment: Yeah, Old Chief Broom has just flown the coop, or the *nest*, as it were.

Comment: Interestingly enough, not much green in the movie of the same name.